# How to pass JavaScript function result to html when using onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how do I place user selected option somewhere in HTML as text. I get user selection using JavaScript but I don't know how to pass it back to HTML.

My current code looks like this.
HTML:

```
<select id="profile" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>                              
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var user_selection = $( "#profile option:selected" ).text();
    alert(user_selection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery create a new element and add it to the DOM like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var user_selection = $("#profile option:selected").text();
    $('<div>' + user_selection + '</div>').insertAfter('#profile');
}
```

Also note that using the `on*` event attributes is considered outdated. You should use unobtrusive event handlers. As you're already using jQuery, here's how to do that:

```js
$('#profile').change(function() {
    var user_selection = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $('<div>' + user_selection + '</div>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="profile">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>                              
</select>
```

I would suggest you familiarise yourself with the methods jQuery has for creating elements in the DOM [around](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/), [inside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) and [outside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/) existing elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new div and place it where you want. Just add this as html of that div or `append` to it, do whatever you like.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var user_selection = $( "#profile option:selected" ).text();
    $('#somediv').html(user_selection);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="profile" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>                              
</select>
<br/>
<div id = 'somediv'> </div>
```